# Custom useFetch hook React not working with errors

Tags: reactjs

so i'm trying to implement a custom react hook for fetch. It's working fine, but i can't seem to do it with the errors. if i try to display the error in a custom component it's says object is not a valid React child ... okey i know that, but how then it's working when there's no error in the componenet ? Here's the code:

Hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const controller = new AbortController();
        const signal = controller.signal;

        fetch(url, { signal: signal })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                setData([result]);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setError(true);
                setErrorMessage(err);
            })
        return () => {
            setError(false);
            controller.abort();
        };
    }, [url]);

    return { data, error, errorMessage };
};

export default useFetch;
```

Component:

```
const WeatherNow = () => {
    const { city } = useContext(CityContext);
    import ErrorHandler from '../error-component/ErrorHandler';

    
    const { data, error, errorMessage } = useFetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&q=${city}&aqi=no`);

 if (error) {
        return <>
            <ErrorHandler props={errorMessage} />
        </>
    };

    return (
        <>
            {data && data.map(x => (
                <div className="today-forecast" key={city}>
                    <h4>
                        {city}
                    </h4>
                    <div>
                        {x.current.condition.text}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src={x.current.condition.icon} alt='' />
                    </div>
                    <h3>
                        {x.current.feelslike_c} *C
                    </h3>
                    <h5 className='rain-wind'>
                        Rain: {x.current.precip_in}  %   /  Wind: {x.current.wind_kph}  km/h
                    </h5>
                    <div className='links'>
                        <Link to='/hourly'>Hourly</Link> <Link to='/daily'>Daily</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
};
```

The ErrorHandler:

```
import './ErrorHandler.css';
import error from './error.png';

const ErrorHandler = ({ props }) => {
    return (
        <div className="error-component">
            <div>
                <h4>
                    {props}
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src={error} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ErrorHandler;
```

Comment: How does the code in ErrorHandler look? Since errorMessage probably is an object, you can not render it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the `catch (err)` is an `unknown` type, it might return anything and more likely an object with a `message` key.

Try to change the way you are setting the error message and make sure it’s a `string`:

```js
setErrorMessage(typeof err?.message === "string" ? err.message : "Unknown Error");
```

**Warning**

Using `process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY` in client side is not safe at all.

Comment: Yeah, that's another option to do it, but the problem is not with that ... Everything is okay if the input is right, but i can't seem to display the error